# How to see through a rectangle in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to create an effect where you can hover over the webpage with your mouse and it will have a drawing and when you get to an area, you unveil an image. I thought about doing it this way:

- Have an image in the back
- Have a rectangle over it (to hide it)
- Have an element (your mouse) be able to go over the rectangle and delete the portion that your mouse is hovered over on.

How can I do this with p5.js?

I have it on my screen at the moment:

```
    let img;

// function preload() {

// }

function setup() {
  var canvas = createCanvas(
    document.getElementById("myCanvas").offsetWidth,
    document.getElementById("myCanvas").offsetHeight
  );
  canvas.parent("myCanvas");
  // background(32);
  loadImage("../img/monalisa.png", img => {
    image(img, 0, 0);
  });
}

function draw() {
  //   monaLisa();
  rect(0, 0, 300, 300);
  circles();
}

// function monaLisa() {
//   image(img, 0, 0);
// }

function circles() {
  //   fill(255);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 25, 25);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply push that rectangle to the right by such amount of pixels mouse is positioned from left side.

```
let img;
let edgeX = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300,400)
  img = loadImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/300px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg")
}

function draw() {
  // variable updates
  if (mouseX > edgeX && 
      mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= 300 && // mouse within limits of picture
      mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= 400
     ) {
     edgeX = mouseX;
  }

  // actual  rawing
  image(img, 0, 0);
  fill('rgba(50,255,150, 0.5)');
  rect(edgeX, 0, 300, 400);
}
```

[p5 demo](https://editor.p5js.org/agnius/sketches/-zeDwTlWv)

#### EDIT

If you want to uncover just a small segment of picture under the mouse position, then algo may be this:

1. Create 2D rectangle array
2. Loop through rectangles and draw them on top of image
3. If mouse intersects with some rectangle - mark it as *undrawable*

Code:

```
let canvW = 300
let canvH = 400
let img
let dx = 20
let dy = 40
let diff = 3
let blocks

function setup() {
  cursor(CROSS);
  mouseX = -10;
  mouseY = -10;
  createCanvas(canvW,canvH)
  img = loadImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/300px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg")
  blocks = new Array(canvH/dy);
  for (var i=0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
     blocks[i] = new Array(canvW/dx);
  }
}

function draw() {
  // variable updates
  for (var y=0; y < blocks.length; y++) {
    for (var x=0; x < blocks[y].length; x++) {
       if (mouseX >= dx*x && 
           mouseX <= dx*x+dx &&
           mouseY >= dy*y && 
           mouseY <= dy*y+dy
          ) {
         blocks[y][x] = false;
       }
    }
  }

  // actual drawing
  image(img, 0, 0)
  stroke(70,127,240, 100)
  strokeWeight(3)

  for (var y=0; y < blocks.length; y++) {
    for (var x=0; x < blocks[y].length; x++) {
       if (blocks[y][x] !== false) {
         // outer rectangle
         fill(`rgba(50,127,240, 0.5)`)
         rect(dx*x, dy*y, dx, dy)
         // inner rectangle
         fill(`rgba(70,127,240, 0.8)`)
         rect(dx*x+diff, dy*y+diff, dx-2*diff, dy-2*diff)
       }
    }
  }
}
```

[p5 uncover segment demo](https://editor.p5js.org/agnius/sketches/zR7rfcEO1)

Visuals: partly uncovered Mona Lisa if somebody is lazy to check demo:

[image]